# AD "The parameter is incorrect" when joining domain

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, ldap

I set up an Active Directory (AD) Domain Controller on a Windows 2003 server. I let the wizard do all the work.

I can login with the domain users I made. However, when I go to add a computer to the domain I get the incredibly helpful error:

```
The parameter is incorrect
```

Any ideas?

From the NetSetup.log:

```
09/24 21:48:30 NetpDoDomainJoin
09/24 21:48:30 NetpMachineValidToJoin: 'NITROXDM'
09/24 21:48:30 NetpGetLsaPrimaryDomain: status: 0x0
09/24 21:48:30 NetpMachineValidToJoin: status: 0x0
09/24 21:48:30 NetpJoinDomain
09/24 21:48:30     Machine: NITROXDM
09/24 21:48:30     Domain: tdomain
09/24 21:48:30     MachineAccountOU: (NULL)
09/24 21:48:30     Account: tdomain\Administrator
09/24 21:48:30     Options: 0x25
09/24 21:48:30     OS Version: 5.1
09/24 21:48:30     Build number: 2600
09/24 21:48:30     ServicePack: Service Pack 3
09/24 21:48:30 NetpValidateName: checking to see if 'tdomain' is valid as type 3 name
09/24 21:48:30 NetpCheckDomainNameIsValid [ Exists ] for 'tdomain' returned 0x0
09/24 21:48:30 NetpValidateName: name 'tdomain' is valid for type 3
09/24 21:48:30 NetpDsGetDcName: trying to find DC in domain 'tdomain', flags: 0x1020
09/24 21:48:45 NetpDsGetDcName: failed to find a DC having account 'NITROXDM$': 0x525
09/24 21:48:45 NetpDsGetDcName: found DC '\\SRV1' in the specified domain
09/24 21:48:45 NetUseAdd to \\SRV1\IPC$ returned 1219
09/24 21:48:45 Trying add to  \\SRV1\IPC$ using NULL Session
09/24 21:48:45 NullSession NetUseAdd to \\SRV1\IPC$ returned 1219
09/24 21:48:45 NetpJoinDomain: status of connecting to dc '\\SRV1': 0x4c3
09/24 21:48:45 NetpDoDomainJoin: status: 0x4c3
```

Comment: Are there any additional logs in the system event log?

Comment: Not really. On the server There is a Directory Service node. There is a ton of info entries there. But no errors or warnings. Client side... Nothing.

Comment: I don't know if matters... this is the Enterprise edition.

Comment: that is a strange error, did you let the wizard create the dns servers for you also?  from the workstation does the dns info make sense?

Comment: what's on the workstation's netsetup.log?

Comment: @tony roth - Yes the wizard set up the dns server on the same box. The client's dns is set to the AD server.

Comment: I have another computer I tried to add to the domain. It can find a SRV record for the domain.

Comment: @natxo asenjo - I added to the question.

Comment: error 1219 is according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681383%28VS.85%29.aspx "ERROR_SESSION_CREDENTIAL_CONFLICT
1219 (0x4C3); Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, using more than one user name, are not allowed. Disconnect all previous connections to the server or shared resource and try again." Do you have any net connections to the domain controller (check net use) ?

Comment: from the workstatin can you nslookup fqdn of your domain.

Comment: @natxo asenjo -- Good call. I had a mapped drive to that server.

Comment: ok, after unmapping permanently that drive, can you join the workstation to the domain?

Comment: @natxo asenjo -- Indeed. Make your comment an answer so I can mark it. ;)

Comment: @NitroxDM: glad it worked! I added an answer to the question ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the problem was that the machine in question had a mapped drive with the domain controller.

error 1219 in the netsetup.log is according to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681383%28VS.85%29.aspx)  "ERROR_SESSION_CREDENTIAL_CONFLICT 1219 (0x4C3); Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, using more than one user name, are not allowed. Disconnect all previous connections to the server or shared resource and try again."

Answer (score 0):

Try dcdiag and netdiag from Support tools. Ensure that the computer uses DC DNS server.
Check this DNS for access with nslookup against the DC records.